# Return an Array via UDF

Tags: excel, vba

I have two macros.  One of them creates an array based on a range.  The second will take that array, go through it and remove any duplicate entries. I then want the second macro to return an Array that I can continue using in the first macro.

Here's what I've tried so far:

This is to get the array:

```
Sub array_Test()
Dim array1() As Variant
ReDim array1(1 To 10)
array1 = Range("A1:A10")
GEN_USE_Remove_Duplicates_from_Array (array1)
Dim i As Integer
Debug.Print Join(array1, "/") 'Now that array1 has had duplicates removed, print the remaining numbers.  This is where I don't know what to do
For i = 0 To UBound(array1)
    Range(Cells(i + 1, 2).Value) = array1(i + 1)
Next i
End Sub
```

And here's that GEN_USE_Remove_Duplicates... sub:

```
Sub GEN_USE_Remove_Duplicates_from_Array(arr As Variant)
Dim Array_1
    Array_1 = arr
Dim Array_2()
Dim Array_toRemove()

Dim dic As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim arrItem, x As Long
For Each arrItem In Array_1
    If Not dic.Exists(arrItem) Then
        dic.Add arrItem, arrItem
    End If
Next

Array_2 = dic.Keys


Debug.Print Join(Array_2, "/")

GEN_USE_Remove_Duplicates_from_Array = Array_2

End Sub
```

That successfully keeps only unique values.  Now, how do I get that result (Array_2) to be used in the array_Test sub?  Do I need to create a function instead of a Sub?

Thanks so much for any advice/help/tips!

Comment: try `function GEN_USE_Remove_Duplicates_from_Array(arr As Variant) ... end function` and assign the returned array to an array like `array1 = GEN_USE_Remove_Duplicates_from_Array (array1)`.

Comment: Aha! That did it - I tried doing the function thing, but didn't think to do the `array1 = GEN_USE_Remove...(array1)`.  Thanks so much Jeeped, as always!!

Edit: Meta question - can I mark your comment as an answer? Or can you put that in an "Answer" so I can do so, so you get the credit you deserve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro `Sub` isn't going to return a value but you can easily swap it out to a function that will.

```
function GEN_USE_Remove_Duplicates_from_Array(arr As Variant)
    ' lots of code stuff here ...
    GEN_USE_Remove_Duplicates_from_Array = Array_2
end function
```

Assign the returned array to an array like,

```
array1 = GEN_USE_Remove_Duplicates_from_Array(array1)
```

fwiw, you should be able to leave it as a sub and use,

```
arr = array2
```

That should also change the array passed in as the single parameter to the de-duped array.

Comment: If I leave the GEN_USE as a sub, how to I run that from array_Test()?  I tried `GEN_USE_Remove_Duplicates_from_Array (array1)` but when the array_Test() sub gets to `Debug.Print Join(array1, "/")` I get a runtime error '5', "invalid procedure call or argument" .

Comment: Assuming that `array2` has been successfully created as a non-duped array from `arr` then the last line in the sub should be `arr = array2`. This reassigns the `arr` array passed into the sub to have the values from the de-duped `array2`. In this case, you would simply call the 'helper' sub with `GEN_USE_Remove_Duplicates_from_Array array1` as it is transforming its parameter, not returning the array like a function does.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, I think just changing `GEN_USE_Remove_Duplicates_from_Array (array1)` to `GEN_USE_Remove_Duplicates_from_Array array1` did the trick.  Thanks a ton again!